# How to print http message in beast 1.7

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast

I can't print base of http request, since migration to beast 1.70.0

I previously done that by:

```
std::cerr << ctx.res.base()
```

but currently looks like operator isn't overloaded, how to do it in 1.70.0?

problem can be reproduced with following code: (mind that beast 1.70.0 should be used)

```
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http/write.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::beast;

http::response<http::string_body> res {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << res.base();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Boost 1.70 which is fixed in version 1.71. A work-around is to define the macro `BOOST_BEAST_ALLOW_DEPRECATED` for your build.